# How do I loop through my class properties and get their types?

Tags: c#, class, reflection, properties

I want to loop through the properties of my class and get each properties type.  I got it most of the way, but when trying to get the type, instead of getting string, int, etc, I get the type reflection.  Any ideas?  Let me know if more background information is needed.  Thanks!

```
using System.Reflection;

Type oClassType = this.GetType(); //I'm calling this inside the class
PropertyInfo[] oClassProperties = oClassType.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in oClassProperties)  //Loop thru properties works fine
{
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.GetType()) == typeof(int))
        //should be integer type but prop.GetType() returns System.Reflection
    else if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.GetType()) == typeof(string))
        //should be string type but prop.GetType() returns System.Reflection
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, you can't use `prop.GetType()` here - that is the type *of the PropertyInfo* - you mean `prop.PropertyType`.

Secondly, try:

```
var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
```

this will work whether it is nullable *or* non-nullable, since GetUnderlyingType will return `null` if it isn't `Nullable<T>`.

Then, after that:

```
if(type == typeof(int)) {...}
else if(type == typeof(string)) {...}
```

or alternative:

```
switch(Type.GetTypeCode(type)) {
    case TypeCode.Int32: /* ... */ break;
    case TypeCode.String: /* ... */ break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you even need to use the Nullable.GetUnderlyingType if the PropertyType is actually accessed with reflecion?

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.  The `PropertyInfo` class has a property `PropertyType` which returns the type of the property.  When you call `GetType()` on the `PropertyInfo` instance you are actually just getting the `RuntimePropertyInfo` which is the type of the member you are reflecting upon.

So, to get the Type of all the member Properties, you would just have to do something like: 
`oClassType.GetProperties().Select(p => p.PropertyType)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the PropertyType property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype